# CPU Resources and Clock Cycles: System.out.println Or Incrementing a flag

Tags: java, android, optimization, micro-optimization

To debug our Android code we have put `System.out.println(string)` which will let us know how many times a function has been called. The other method would have been to put a flag and keep on incrementing it after every function call. And then at the end printing the final value of flag by `System.out.println(...)`. (practically in my application the function will be called thousands of time)

My question is: In terms of ***CPU Resources*** and ***Clock Cycles*** which one is lighter: increment operation Or System.out.println?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incrementing is going to be *much, much* more efficient - especially if you've actually got anywhere for that output to go. Think of all the operations required by `System.out.println` vs incrementing a variable. Of course, whether the impact will actually be *significant* is a different matter - and if your method is already doing a lot of work, then a `System.out.println` call may not actually make much difference. But if you just want to know how many times it was called, then keeping a counter makes more sense than looking through the logs anyway, IMO.

I would recommend using [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) or [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead of just having a primitive variable, as that way you get simple thread-safety.

Comment: Thanks for your reply with clarity. I think Atomic operations will be costly (my application is single threaded)...

Comment: @gpuguy: You *think*, or you've benchmarked and *proved* it? Compared with `System.out.println`, an atomic operation will be very cheap indeed. It'll be slightly more expensive than a non-atomic operation, but still cheap. If you're really, *really* single-threaded then you can probably get away with a simple primitive operation, but you should be very aware that in a threaded environment it may lead to problems.

Comment: Basically you are right. I tested atomic operations in multi-threaded apps using CUDA and OpenCL. Atomic increment operation is costlier than simple increment. However Atomic operations came to rescue in many of the situations....

Answer (score 0):

Incrementing will be a *lot* faster in terms of clock cycles.  Assuming the increment is fairly close to a hardware increment it would only take a couple of clock cycles.  That means you can do millions every second.

On the other hand System.out.println will have to call out to the OS.  Use stdout.  Convert characters, etc.  Each of these steps will take many, many clock cycles.

Coming back to your original question, if you're looking at how many times a function gets called you could try and run a profiler - there are various desktop and android solutions available.  That way you wouldn't need to pollute your code with counting/printing, and you can keep your production code lean.

Again thinking a litle further, why would you like to know exact number of times a function is called?  If you're concerned about a defect consider writing some unit tests that will prove exactly how many times a function gets called.  If you're concerned about performance, perhaps look at load test techniques in combination with your profiler.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I agree I should use Profiler. But the issue is in Android TarceView, no information comes for native code (which is having my function I want to count).